# Hash functions soldity to python

Tags: solidity, python, hash

In Solidity, I run the following code:

```
function hashTest() public returns(bytes32,bytes32,bytes32) {
bytes32 _solution = 0xbc756c25d68ea2f260ea5f15e1e1c734c019cbc014270dd386eacca4699f60f6;
bytes32 v = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(_solution));
bytes32 x = sha256(abi.encodePacked(_solution));
bytes32 z = ripemd160(abi.encodePacked(_solution));
Print(v,x,z);
return(v,x,z);
```

I want to replicate in python, but so far I can only get the first (the one supported by Web3), does anyone know how to get the others?  Here's my current try:

```
def testHash():
    _solutions = '0xbc756c25d68ea2f260ea5f15e1e1c734c019cbc014270dd386eacca4699f60f6';
    v = Web3.toHex(Web3.sha3(hexstr=_solutions))
    x = "0x" + hashlib.new('sha256',str.encode(_solutions)).hexdigest()
    z= hashlib.new('ripemd160',str.encode(_solutions)).hexdigest()
    print("v",v)
    print("x",x);
    print("z",z);
```

So like I said, the top matches, but the other two don't

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you are treating the hex string as a string. You should convert the string to bytes using bytes.fromhex(). Note that you should remove the `0x` from the string. Like this:

```
_solutions = '0xbc756c25d68ea2f260ea5f15e1e1c734c019cbc014270dd386eacca4699f60f6';
v = Web3.toHex(Web3.sha3(hexstr=_solutions))
x = "0x" + hashlib.new('sha256',bytes.fromhex(_solutions[2:])).hexdigest()
z= hashlib.new('ripemd160',bytes.fromhex(_solutions[2:])).hexdigest()
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're a valiant shining knight.  Thanks for helping out, this works great